# Forwarding a subdomain to another subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, forwarding

I want do redirect a request to one domain to another domain with keeping the requested subdomain and in the best case the path as well.

For example:

```
example.com                     to  example.net
www.example.com                 to  www.example.net
sub1.example.com                to  sub1.example.net

subxyz.example.com/test.html    to  subxyz.example.net/test.html
```

Especially, it is important for me to submit the subdomain.
I am looking forward to any possible solution on a shared web host so probably a solution using `.htaccess`?

When using `.htaccess`: Would it be possible as well to redirect any domain (pointing on the directory with the `.htaccess` file without specify the origin domain) to a specific domain with submitting the subdomain?

Comment: What did you try already? Did you look at the numerous other questions here about redirections?

Comment: Hey, unfortunately, I couldn't really find my question in another thread but couldn't find it. Also the linked post by Martin is not equal to my problem.
I just tried the basic forwarding tools from my webhoster all-inkl.de but it's not handling the subdomains like desired